# .change does not work for select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in a view:

```
<div class="wrap_select">
            @Html.DropDownList("dateRange", new SelectList(Model.DateRange, "Value","Text"), new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                      {"class", "styled"}                                                                            
                })
 </div>
```

and `JS`  in the same view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dateRange").change(function () {
            $("#scheduleList").load("/EventSchedule/GetScheduleList/");
        });
    });
```

But,  my `GetScheduleList` action not call. Where is a problem?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Html code:

```
<div class="wrap_select">
  <span class="select" id="selectdateRange">27 марта, Вт</span>
  <select class="styled" id="dateRange" name="dateRange">
    <option value="23.03.2012 0:00:00">Сегодня, 23 марта, Пт</option>
    <option value="24.03.2012 0:00:00">Завтра, 24 марта, Сб</option>
    <option value="25.03.2012 0:00:00">25 марта, Вс</option>
    <option value="26.03.2012 0:00:00">26 марта, Пн</option>
    <option value="27.03.2012 0:00:00">27 марта, Вт</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2:** Im using `custom form element` by Ryan Fait. May be there are some errors.

```
/*

CUSTOM FORM ELEMENTS

Created by Ryan Fait
www.ryanfait.com

The only things you may need to change in this file are the following
variables: checkboxHeight, radioHeight and selectWidth (lines 24, 25, 26)

The numbers you set for checkboxHeight and radioHeight should be one quarter
of the total height of the image want to use for checkboxes and radio
buttons. Both images should contain the four stages of both inputs stacked
on top of each other in this order: unchecked, unchecked-clicked, checked,
checked-clicked.

You may need to adjust your images a bit if there is a slight vertical
movement during the different stages of the button activation.

The value of selectWidth should be the width of your select list image.

Visit http://ryanfait.com/ for more information.

*/

var checkboxHeight = "25";
var radioHeight = "25";
var selectWidth = "140";


/* No need to change anything after this */


document.write('<style type="text/css">input.styled { display: none; } select.styled { position: relative; width: ' + selectWidth + 'px; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); z-index: 5; } .disabled { opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50); }</style>');

var Custom = {
    init: function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), span = Array(), textnode, option, active;
        for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
            if((inputs[a].type == "checkbox" || inputs[a].type == "radio") && inputs[a].className == "styled") {
                span[a] = document.createElement("span");
                span[a].className = inputs[a].type;

                if(inputs[a].checked == true) {
                    if(inputs[a].type == "checkbox") {
                        position = "0 -" + (checkboxHeight*2) + "px";
                        span[a].style.backgroundPosition = position;
                    } else {
                        position = "0 -" + (radioHeight*2) + "px";
                        span[a].style.backgroundPosition = position;
                    }
                }
                inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
                inputs[a].onchange = Custom.clear;
                if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                    span[a].onmousedown = Custom.pushed;
                    span[a].onmouseup = Custom.check;
                } else {
                    span[a].className = span[a].className += " disabled";
                }
            }
        }
        inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
        for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
            if(inputs[a].className == "styled") {
                option = inputs[a].getElementsByTagName("option");
                active = option[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                textnode = document.createTextNode(active);
                for(b = 0; b < option.length; b++) {
                    if(option[b].selected == true) {
                        textnode = document.createTextNode(option[b].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                    }
                }
                span[a] = document.createElement("span");
                span[a].className = "select";
                span[a].id = "select" + inputs[a].name;
                span[a].appendChild(textnode);
                inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
                if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                    inputs[a].onchange = Custom.choose;
                } else {
                    inputs[a].previousSibling.className = inputs[a].previousSibling.className += " disabled";
                }
            }
        }
        document.onmouseup = Custom.clear;
    },
    pushed: function() {
        element = this.nextSibling;
        if(element.checked == true && element.type == "checkbox") {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*3 + "px";
        } else if(element.checked == true && element.type == "radio") {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*3 + "px";
        } else if(element.checked != true && element.type == "checkbox") {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight + "px";
        } else {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight + "px";
        }
    },
    check: function() {
        element = this.nextSibling;
        if(element.checked == true && element.type == "checkbox") {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
            element.checked = false;
        } else {
            if(element.type == "checkbox") {
                this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*2 + "px";
            } else {
                this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*2 + "px";
                group = this.nextSibling.name;
                inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
                    if(inputs[a].name == group && inputs[a] != this.nextSibling) {
                        inputs[a].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
                    }
                }
            }
            element.checked = true;
        }
    },
    clear: function() {
        inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var b = 0; b < inputs.length; b++) {
            if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
                inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*2 + "px";
            } else if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
                inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
            } else if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
                inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*2 + "px";
            } else if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
                inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
            }
        }
    },
    choose: function() {
        option = this.getElementsByTagName("option");
        for(d = 0; d < option.length; d++) {
            if(option[d].selected == true) {
                document.getElementById("select" + this.name).childNodes[0].nodeValue = option[d].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
window.onload = Custom.init;
```

PS. Firebug does not show any errors.

Comment: change() should be working for select, can U pass the actual html code?

Comment: well when I try it and add $("#dateRange").change(function () {
        console.log('smt');
            $("#scheduleList").load("/EventSchedule/GetScheduleList/"); 
        }); // the console log is written, so problem must be with the load line

Comment: I also added a simple div <div id="scheduleList"></div> to the code and it gives me error page not found now.

Comment: @OriesokVlassky: very strange, I added `console.log` in my code, but there is nothing.

Comment: okay, I suggest to try console log the  $("#dateRange") object, U may find it is not the only one in your html

Comment: I tried  it. Only one dateRange on page.

Comment: edited my answer with solution

Comment: @OriesokVlassky: I have notice that when I select value then `selected` attribute not add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the example bellow with the jQuery.on() API method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".wrap_select").on("change",function () {
        $("#scheduleList").load("/EventSchedule/GetScheduleList/");
    });
});
```

EDIT:

The problem was event bubbling there so the event is thrown on the parent(container div) instead.

So the solution is:

> http://jsfiddle.net/KP3jU/4/

Comment: can you debug with firebug and see if there is any error in the console ?

Comment: i am sorry but i don't have any knowledge about "custom form element by Ryan Fait"